# Reason for 100% peak load on firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I don't publish my app and it showing load 100% peak, what is the issue?

[image]

Comment: Are you downloading any images from Firebase storage?

Comment: yes , using picasso , only 12 small size images

Comment: The peak may be caused when you’re testing the app and downloading the images over and over as you test. You might want to do your normal testing and see if another peak happens.